# How to force SQL Server to write partial query set to table during select

Tags: sql-server-2017, linked-server

I'm trying to run a select query to extract a data set from a linked server, to be stored on SQL server.

It seems that SQL server is storing the rows of the partial data set in memory and writing it to the table only when the full data set has been retrieved. Problem is that the data set is large, and the connection times out frequently.

Is there any way to get SQL server to write parts of the data set downloaded thus far to the destination table instead of storing it in memory?

Comment: Single query cannot be executed partially. Divide your dataset (for example by ID range) and get it chunk-by-chunk until all chunks got successfully.

Comment: Shucks, was hoping that wouldn't be the case. Oh well.